# OneNote in Dynamics 365 - sharing set up

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, onenote, dynamics-365

We are setting up a OneNote integration to D365. It appears that only members of the same site can create a OneNote from a record in D365. My concern is that the records in D365 may have sharing restrictions, however notebooks appear all on one site. How could I prevent other members of a site from seeing notes which are not shared with them?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I have received from Dynamics 365 Team: The Dynamics security role and privileges cannot be enforced in Sharepoint/OneNote. We advise customers to limit the number of user members to access Sharepoint.